# Making column headers in Kendo Grid editable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with rows and columns .
I want to make the grid column headers editable so that user can change them and these changes are to be reflected in data model .

i went through the documentation of kendo but could not find any thing related to making grid headers editable .

Thanks

Comment: What is the idea behind changing the headers and the model? It is not supported simply because the idea is showing data and if you change the model via changing the header you will have a different model that you will have to reload.

Comment: The idea is to enable user to give his own column name . Yes I understand that it will change the model, but thats exactly my requirement. After the user changes the header, next time he will see the data with his column headers and not previous default headers

Comment: i am having the exact same issue. Have u managed to find the solution ?

Comment: No. Seems like its not editable . We are exploring other options or workarounds.